# 0.25秒おきに数値を１ずつ増やす方法を教えていただきたいです

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

時間に連動して数値が増加するというコードを書きたいです。
以下コードのように１秒おきの数値増加はできるのですが、
0.25秒おきのような小数点以下の数値増加ができません。
方法はいろいろと試したのですがなかなかうまくいかず、詰まってしまいました。

```
  if let t = self.startTime {
        let time: Double = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - t + self.elapsedTime
        let sec: Int = Int(time)
        let msec: Int = Int((time - Double(sec)) * 100.0)
        self.timerLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", sec/60, sec%60, msec) as String
        self.resultLabel.text = NSString(format: "%01d", sec * 4) as String
    }
```

上記コードの
`self.resultLabel.text = NSString(format: "%01d", sec * 4) as String`

部分が数値を増加させるLabelになります。
現在は１秒で数値が４ずつ増えるようになっていますが、
ここを0.25秒で数値が１ずつ増える設定にしたいと思っています。
情報が不足しておりましたら、追加致しますので教えていただければと思います。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: この処理は1秒間に何回実行されるようになっていますか?

Comment: ご返信遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。
1秒間に1回実行されるようになってます。

Answer (score 1):

`let sec: Int = Int(time)`の時点でデータの粒度が下がっていますので、その後4倍しても1秒ごとに4増えるだけになります。

```
  if let t = self.startTime {
    let time: Double = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - t + self.elapsedTime
    let sec: Int = Int(time)
    let sec4: Int = Int(time * 4)
    let msec: Int = Int((time - Double(sec)) * 100.0)
    self.timerLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", sec/60, sec%60, msec) as String
    self.resultLabel.text = NSString(format: "%01d", sec4) as String
  }
```

とするのが良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そちらで試してみたいと思います！

Comment: 1秒間に1回しか実行されないと、上記コードでも1秒で数値が4ずつしか増えませんので、もっと細かく実行されるようにしてくださいね！

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事できました！